# Mouse Wheel event not firing on one computer, works on another

Tags: c#, wpf, hwnd

Here's the problem:

I wrote a WPF application that uses an Hwnd to host a drawing surface.  That hwnd is responsible for sending back mouse events that happen.  On my computer, everything works normally and I see the 522(0x020A) mouse wheel message without issue.

I installed this same software on another computer, and the event didn't fire.  I went as far as logging all event messages to a file to see if 522 fired at all, and it never showed up.

Things I've tried:

-Making sure the Hwnd has focus. Not only did I make a thread that would re-focus it every second, I made sure that on my computer (working) "IsFocused" was true for that hwnd.

-Closing down *any* other program running.  This included things normal to the computer running in the background, in case something was taking focus off.

-Switching the mouse.  I used the mouse I'm using on my computer to be sure, and it still did not work on the new computer.

Here's the base code:

```
public abstract class Win32HwndControl : HwndHost
{
    protected IntPtr Hwnd { get; private set; }
    protected bool HwndInitialized { get; private set; }

    private const string WindowClass = "HwndWrapper";

    protected Win32HwndControl()
    {
    }

protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent)
{
    var wndClass = new NativeMethods.WndClassEx();
    wndClass.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(wndClass);
    wndClass.hInstance = NativeMethods.GetModuleHandle(null);
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = NativeMethods.DefaultWindowProc;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = WindowClass;
    wndClass.hCursor = NativeMethods.LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, NativeMethods.IDC_ARROW);
    NativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(ref wndClass);

    Hwnd = NativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(
            0, WindowClass, "", NativeMethods.WS_CHILD | NativeMethods.WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, (int)Width, (int)Height, hwndParent.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

    return new HandleRef(this, Hwnd);
 }

 protected override IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case NativeMethods.WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                RaiseMouseEvent(MouseButton.Left, Mouse.MouseDownEvent);
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_LBUTTONUP:
                RaiseMouseEvent(MouseButton.Left, Mouse.MouseUpEvent);
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
                RaiseMouseEvent(MouseButton.Right, Mouse.MouseDownEvent);
                break;

            case NativeMethods.WM_RBUTTONUP:
                RaiseMouseEvent(MouseButton.Right, Mouse.MouseUpEvent);
                break;
            case NativeMethods.WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                RaiseMouseWheelEvent(wParam.ToInt32(), Mouse.MouseWheelEvent);
                break;

        }

        return base.WndProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam, ref handled);
    }
```

There is more code to this class, but I've confirmed it is not hitting the WndProc method.

Any tips on why this would be happening on one computer and not the other?

Comment: Try getting the last error : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/GetLastError.html

Comment: Crystal ball says that one machine boots Win10 and the other an older version.  Mouse wheel notification was changed in Win10, it now sends to the window being hovered instead of the window that has the focus.

Comment: I am on Windows 10, and the other machine is Windows 7.  So this still seems like a focus issue?

Comment: I have the same issue on different Windows 10 machines, but on most it works.